# A plothole in Death Note The Last Name?

Tags: death-note

I just noticed something. So in death note the last name, L got the death note, after he watched Misa killing criminals with the death note. He then replaced her death note with a fake one. But here's the problem. L said, that they made fake news that the criminals Misa ''killed'' died, but Misa should've seen that they were still alive, because a rule in the death note states, that a person who's dead, doesn't have a name or a lifespan above their head in a picture.

Rule XXXIX:

Humans that have traded for the eye power of a god of death cannot see the name or life span of humans who have already passed away by looking at their photos.

Answer (score 1):

Fake doesn't necessarily mean not convincing.  Remember, by this time L knew that there were more than one and that the second had an ability that the first did not have.  L knew this and arranged the fake information but also used dead bodies.  He even went to the trouble to find people with the same name.  L actually uses that same tactic twice in the series.

Comment: did i missed something? because i never saw him using that tactic twice.

Comment: same name as the people who died? really? been awhile since I've seen the movies

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler alert:

> Something similar happens in the Death Note 2015 series.

The explanation there might help answer your question. Elaboration:

> Mikami also fell for fake news. Misa didn't check the faces likely. She just read the news that this or that person died.

Been a while since I've seen the movies. I'm guessing based on the above.

Comment: Currently as it stand this Answer does not answer the question. to avoid down-votes i highly suggest you expand on what you are referring to. you have demonstrated that you know to use spoilers so you can use those to hide spoiler information, however keep in mind that the question is addressing [Death Note 2: The Last Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note_2:_The_Last_Name)